# function pointers and pointer arguments in C

Tags: c, arguments, function-pointers

Complete noob to `C`, just getting started with some goofing around, wondering how (read "*if*") the following is possible.

Trying to create a `struct`, with a member that is a function pointer, and the function pointer points to a function that takes an argument with the same type as the aforementioned `struct`. For example (mind the syntax, just getting familiar here):

```
typedef struct{
    void (*myStructFunc)(void);
} MyStructType;

void myFunc(void){
    printf("Hello world!");
}

// ...

MyStructType myStruct;
myStruct.myStructFunc = &myFunc;
myStruct.myStructFunc(); // <= Hello world!
```

**This** works fine, but when I try to introduce arguments of the `MyStructType` type to the function:

```
typedef struct{
    void (*myStructFunc)(*MyStructType); // <= parse error
} MyStructType;

void myFunc(MyStructType *myStruct){
    printf("Hello world!");
}

// ...

MyStructType myStruct;
myStruct.myStructFunc = &myFunc;
myStruct.myStructFunc(&myStruct);
```

These examples are brief for obvious reasons, but they illustrate my intentions. Again, just getting my feet wet with `C` so please forgive any syntactical ignorance.

Anyways, how can I achieve this? Clearly I'm doing something incorrect syntactically, or perhaps I'm trying to do something that's plain not possible.

Also note, that the reason for this is purely academic.

Comment: P.S. Have fun implementing OO. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parse error is coming from `*MyStructType`, which appears to be a typo as you've correctly declared the struct pointer in the actual function definition.

Fixing that is still an error because, at the time of the `struct` definition, the `typedef` hasn't taken effect. The same problem can be illustrated (more clearly IMHO) with a linked list:

```
typedef struct {
  node *next; // error - what is a node?
  void *data;
} node; // this is where node is defined
```

To solve it, you need to use a named `struct`:

```
struct node {
  struct node *next;
  void *data;
};
```

Or put the `typedef` first, then define the (again named) `struct`:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node {
  node *next;
  void *data;
};
```

Or (if you're feeling obnoxious) just use a `void *` pointer:

```
typedef struct {
  void *next;
  void *data;
} node;
```

The same applies to your situation.

Comment: **Thanks Chris Lutz;** Much appreciated, as I was just reading into linked list implementations in `C`, so your answer was spot on for now and later :) Gotta say ***StackOverflow* + C *Programming: A Modern Approach*** has gotta be the best way to learn `C`.

Answer (score 5):

In your second example, the name `MyStructType` isn't defined when you're declaring your function.  Also, you have the `*` in the wrong spot.  You need to do something similar to the following:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    void (*myStructFunc)(struct MyStruct *);
} MyStructType;
```

Comment: You might take out the `// <= parse error` because your example works.

Comment: **Thanks lacqui;** Also spot on; gave you the +1 but went with **Chris** for the extra info.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
struct MyStructType {
  void (*myStructFunc)(struct MyStructType*);
};
```

instead.  In C, structs are in their own namespace, so if you want to refer to a struct, you need to prefix the name by `struct`.  Your `typedef` isn't seen until *after* you reference, which is an error.  If you still want the typedef, you can do:

```
typedef MyStructType MyStructType_t;
```